# How to use ASP.NET master page in Sharepoint

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010, master-pages

I have very less idea about Sharepoint but I am very much familiar with ASP.NET. Now I need to develop a master page for sharepoint site. I believe, for that either I can use Sharepoint designer or Visual Studio.
Being a basic ASP.NET developer I can design a page with

.. etc tags and not Sharepoint specific design feature.

Is there any way I can use a Master page of ASP.NET application in SharePoint, as a Master page?

Comment: Have you read this : **http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/Blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=386**

Comment: @huMptyduMpty This link is only talking about the sharepoint master page which we can create in SharePoint but how can I import a ASP.NET Master page to Sharepoint ?

Comment: hmm...may be this helps **http://www.rdacorp.com/wp-content/uploads/ASP-NET-Master-Pages-and-SharePoint.pdf**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Heather Solomon's Blog](http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2011/09/09/just-the-essentials-sharepoint-master-pages/), she has awesome info for dealing with master pages and also branding/design for SharePoint and provides some base master page files to help you get started.